# Cryptographically secure random number generator for software entropy in Node.js

Tags: node.js, security, random, cryptography, entropy

I'm trying to generate key pairs (public and private) and I'm looking for ***cryptographically secure libraries*** that allow me to generate good **entropy** (both hardware and software) in a node.js environment (I know that would suffice
128 bits or more of entropy to be safe).

I'm currently using the node.js **`crypto`** module which, I know is a secure module as it uses a software based random number generation algorithm, which uses the entropy collected by the operating system as a seed to generate cryptographically secure random numbers (The entropy collected by the operating system can include sources of hardware entropy, such as mouse movement or thermal noise in circuitry, but also other sources of software entropy, such as the system timestamp or clock frequency).

To increase my basic entropy (I'm currently using **`crypto.randomBytes(32)`** , so 256 bits) and to diversify the generation of random numbers, I wanted to use another secure module to have a single combined entropy which I will then use for key generation and feel comfortable in terms of safety.

> My main goal is to have a sufficiently random and uniformly distributed source of entropy.

To all security experts and to those who have had experience in this regard, I ask if it is necessary (or recommended) to add more entropy by diversifying the ways to generate randomness, or even just the crypto module is fine. Such advice would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using the `crypto` module is fine.  In Node.js, the `crypto.randomBytes` function comes from OpenSSL's CSPRNG, which is a well-known, tested design (an AES-CTR DRBG), seeded from the operating system's CSPRNG.  The DRBG design and tests are from NIST and have been reviewed by cryptographers around the world, and all major operating systems have strong CSPRNGs.

If you tried to do your own entropy collection, you'd probably wouldn't end up doing a very good job, since most of the best entropy sources are hardware timings and possibly hardware devices, and mostly that's best collected in the kernel.  That's why most cryptographers recommend using the operating system's CSPRNG (or a secure cryptographic library such as OpenSSL using it) instead of trying to do it yourself.  256 bits of entropy is expected to be fine for all current and future computing needs due to the fact that our planet lacks sufficient resources to store even 2^128 bits of data using the theoretical minimum energy, so you can simply do what you're doing without concern.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. So, I'll use it!